# Displaying multiple lines in Joptionpane?

Tags: java

Hi Im new to this forum and also new to java, I need some help for my intro to java homework. Ive done most of the logic. The problem is to write a program that displays all the numbers from 100 to 1000, ten per line, that are divisible by 5 and 6. Numbers are separated by exactly one space. My professor wants it to be done in a Joptionpane window. When I try to do that, only one answer pops up in a window. How do I make my answers appear ten in a line, separated by exactly one space in only one window? My professor wants us to use an escape function to be able to display the lines of answer.

```
public class FindFactors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "";
        final int NumbersPerLine = 10;    // Display 10 numbers per line
        int count = 0; // Count the number of numbers divisible by 5 and 6

        // Test all numbers from 100 to 1,000

        for (int i = 100; i <= 1000; i++) {
            // Test if number is divisible by 5 and 6
            message = message + " " + i;
            count++;
            if (count == 10) {
                message = message + "\r\n";
                count = 0;
            }
            if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 6 == 0) {
                count++;    // increment count
                // Test if numbers per line is 10
                if (count % NumbersPerLine == 0)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i);
                else
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (i + " "));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below approach, a slight change to your code and will give the required output.

```
public class FindFactors {
public static void main(String[] args) {
final int NumbersPerLine = 10;    // Display 10 numbers per line
int count = 0; // Count the number of numbers divisible by 5 and 6
// Test all numbers from 100 to 1,000
String numbersPerLine = "";
for (int i = 100; i <= 1000; i++) {
    // Test if number is divisible by 5 and 6
    if (count == 10) {           
        count = 0;
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 6 == 0) {
        numbersPerLine =numbersPerLine+" "+i;
        count++;    // increment count
        // Test if numbers per line is 10

        if (count % NumbersPerLine == 0) 
            numbersPerLine =numbersPerLine+"\n";
    }
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numbersPerLine);
}
}
```

Comment: **Note** In my solution, I am doing String concatenation inside a loop which is not efficient performance wise but as it's a single program that executes I am doing like that. For Production level code, this String concatenation approach should not be followed.

Comment: First of all thank you for you solution! However when I run your solution, the first line has 9 answers and im required to have 10 answers in one line.

Comment: Just remove the first `count++` increment which is at the beginning of the **for loop**, then it should work and clean up the code by removing the unused String variable **message**.

Comment: @ShawnKuriakose Can you please check the updated code, I tested and its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A `JOptionPane` has the ability to show images, text or any other components, for this particular case you may want to create your own `JPanel` which adds every line of numbers into a `JLabel` and then adds that `JLabel` to it.

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MultiLineOptionPane {
    private JPanel pane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MultiLineOptionPane()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //This object will be used to concatenate in the next for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) { //Sample for loop
            if ((i) % 10 == 0) { //Every 10 numbers we restart the StringBuilder
                pane.add(new JLabel(sb.toString())); //We add a new JLabel to the JPanel with the contents of the StringBuilder
                sb.delete(0, sb.length()); //We restart the StringBuilder
            } else {
                sb.append(i); //We append the current number to the StringBuilder
                sb.append(" "); //We append a space after the number
            }
        }
        pane.add(new JLabel(sb.toString())); //We add the last line of numbers in the StringBuilder to the pane

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), pane, "Numbers", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); //We display the message
    }
}
```

The output for the above program looks like (cropped or it would be too tall):

[image]